# How to get Crash report with Sencha Touch Application

Tags: sencha-touch, crash-reports, bug-reporting

I want get the application crash report for my Sencha Touch application.Can anybody suggest me how i can achieve that..
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you can use window.onerror:

```
window.onerror = function (message, url, lineno) {
  // handle error
}
```